Nextjs -Using Context Api to manage auth sessions casuing an issue on reloading
Backend works fine and it seems to be an issue due to the useEffect hook , It logs me not found user inside of 2nd useEffect and also , the value of user logs null (useruseruser ,null),it immediately redirects to login page , and then the value of user gets updated (useruseruser ,{...user} ). How can i modify my code to resolve this issue . I want to follow the best practises as industry standards and not just a fix. Below is my authContext code
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { createContext, useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import  API_BASE_URL  from '../utils/baseURL'
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import axios from 'axios';
export const userContext = createContext(null);
function AuthContext({ children }) {
    const router=useRouter()
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const[loadingAuth,setLoadingAuth] = useState(true);
    const openRoutes=['/login','/signup']

    useEffect(() => {
        const authtoken = localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log("in ue1")
        if (authtoken) {
            axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/auth`, {
                headers: {
                    'authorization': authtoken
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                     console.log(response.data)
                    setUser(response.data.user);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
                    setUser(null);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    setLoadingAuth(false); 
                });
        } else {
            setUser(null);
            setLoadingAuth(false); 
        }
    }, []);
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("useruseruser",user) 
     
     if (!user && !openRoutes.includes(pathname)) {   
        console.log("not found user")
           router.push('/login');
        }
    }, [!loadingAuth,user]);


    const logout = () => {    
        setUser(null);
        localStorage.removeItem('token'); 
        router.push('/login'); 
    };

    return (
        <userContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser , logout, loadingAuth}}>
            {loadingAuth?<div className=''>Loading.......</div>:children}        
        </userContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default AuthContext;


How do you set authToken in localStorage, and you should add authToken into first useEffect dependencies and remove loadingAuth at the second, otherwise it will trigger at every render.

@DaveLin I set it at time of login
